# Is this supposed to take this long?

Tags: java, android, database, string, performance

**I am using `LocationManager's` `requestLocationUpdates()` to get the user's coordinates on opening the app, and it takes longer to get the coordinates than in other apps.**

Getting location takes a while, however while my app is still loading and waiting for location (I am using `LocationManager's` `requestLocationUpdates()`) for much longer than other apps.

Here is a screenshot of my notification panel when I launch my application:

[image]

Notice it says `Finding Location...` when I open my app, because my app calls `LocationManager's` `requestLocationUpdates()` as soon as the app is opened.

### Here's the meat of the question:

Even while this notification is in my presence, if I navigate to an app like google maps, it is able to pinpoint my exact location in a matter of seconds. Is that because google maps uses `getLastLocation`?

How come other apps are able to fetch location much faster than mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are two ways of getting location-  fine (gps) and coarse (network).  Google Play Services provides a 3rd method, but it uses a combo of those two.  GPS takes a long time-  it literally has to talk to 7 out of 2 dozen or so satellites to get a location for the first time.  Network is fast, it just needs 1 network request (or less if data is cached).

A lot of apps will use both simultaneously, using the network to get a fast answer, and then improving to GPS when it gets that data.  I know maps does this.  This will get you a fast inaccurate answer, and allow you to improve the accuracy later.

You can use getLastKnownLoacation to go even quicker, but you have to be able to deal with it returning null.  Generally network is fast enough.

Comment: You say that Google Play Services uses a combo of those two. Could you explain a little on how it does that? Thanks

Comment: Oh okay. So when I do get my location, I store it in a class reference, and retrieve it with getters and setters. How can I check if the value stored is null or not before initializing my object? For example, the user comes to my app, it starts fetching location, user leaves my app open and goes to another app for 30 seconds, then user comes back to my app. When they come back, I don't want to request for the location **again**, because that would take a lot of time again. Instead, in my `onResume()`, I want to check like so:

Comment: `if(myLocationObject == null && myLocationObject.getLongitude() == 0 && myLocationObject.getLatitude() == 0) { startRequestingUpdatesBecauseTheUserHasn'tAlreadyRequestedUpdatesYet();`

Comment: However, if the `myLocationObject` is null, then I get `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double curlybrace.ruchir.appName.LocationClass.getLongitude()' on a null object reference`

Comment: So I basically want the user to be able to leave my app **while** the location is being requested, and so when they come back, if the values are not null, then I can use those values instead of requesting again. However, I am getting a null pointer exception. How can I fix this? I am sure there is a very simple solution that I just cant see... :)

Comment: I think you meant !=null  in there-  with a check for equal to null you'll always either skip the block or have an NPE

Comment: Okay, basically I just want to show a dialog to the user while my app is fetching the location using requestLocationUpdates(). How do I do that? Thanks

Comment: Here is what I've been trying for the last two days, but it doesn't work still. For some reason, the toast shows up right when I start the thread: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1107887225647370f8fecace77558fd2

Comment: All I am trying to do is show the user that my app is getting the location, and that they should wait patiently.

Comment: How can I achieve this? Thanks